# What is the difference between final Class and Class?

Tags: swift

What is the difference between final Class and Class?

```
final class A {

}

class B {    

}
```

Comment: `A` can't be extended https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

Comment: @Héctor You mean inherited from; extension is an entirely different thing in Swift.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Final is class modifier which prevents it from being inherited or being overridden. From apple documentation

> You can prevent a method, property, or subscript from being overridden
>   by marking it as **final**. Do this by writing the final modifier
>   before the method, property, or subscript’s introducer keyword (such
>   as final var, final func, final class func, and final subscript).
>
> Any attempt to override a final method, property, or subscript in a
>   subclass is reported as a compile-time error. Methods, properties, or
>   subscripts that you add to a class in an extension can also be marked
>   as final within the extension’s definition.
>
> You can mark an entire class as final by writing the final modifier
>   before the class keyword in its class definition (final class). Any
>   attempt to subclass a final class is reported as a compile-time error.

Answer (score 96):

Classes marked with `final` can not be overridden.

---

**Why should one care at all whether class can or can't be overridden?**

There are two things to consider:

1. As an API designer/developer, you might have a class in your Framework that  can be abused or misused when subclassed. `final` prevents class to be subclassed—mission accomplished. You can also use `final` to mark methods, properties, and even subscripts of non-final classes. This will have same effect, but for particular part of the class.
2. Marking class as `final` also tells *Swift compiler* that method should be called directly (static dispatch) rather than looking up a function from a method table (dynamic dispatch). This reduces function call overhead and gives you extra performance. You can [read more on this](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27) on Swift Developer Blog.

Comment: I want to add another (imo important) reason when to add final to a class: You as the developer simply have not thought about inheritance while designing the class. To show this to your colleagues (or the user of your class) add `final`. If inheritance will be necessary later on, the final modifier will remind you to think the refactoring through.

Comment: Great answer. Interesting how I did detect a performance boost in my whole app. I had all classes in my project declared without the `final` keyword, as I didn't subclass almost any of those, adding the `final` keyword really gave me a performance boost.

Comment: You don't need `final` on *internal* declarations when you use Whole Module Optimization, it's inferred (see the linked Swift Developer Blog post).

Answer (score 22):

> Use final when you know that a declaration does not need to be
>   overridden. The final keyword is a restriction on a class, method, or
>   property that indicates that the declaration **cannot be overridden**.
>   This allows the compiler to safely elide dynamic dispatch indirection.

Read more:

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27

Answer (score 14):

Final means that no one can inherit from this class.

Answer (score 10):

Besides `final` declaration does not need to be overridden also has better performance than no use `final`, because `final` disable dynamic dispatch at runtime which save runtime overhead.

Answer (score 9):

Hoping I can boil down the other answers into this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that helped me:

```swift
          open class Open {}     // Anyone can see, anything can subclass
public         class Normal {}   // Anyone can see, internal can subclass
internal       class Internal {} // Internal can see, internal can subclass
public   final class Final {}    // Anyone can see, nothing can subclass
```

In your project/module:

```swift
class SubOpen:     Open {}     // OK
class SubNormal:   Normal {}   // OK
class SubInternal: Internal {} // OK
class SubFinal:    Final {}    // Error: Can't subclass
```

In some other project/module:

```swift
class SubOpen:     Open {}     // OK
class SubNormal:   Normal {}   // Error: Can't subclass
class SubInternal: Internal {} // Error: `Internal` type not found
class SubFinal:    Final {}    // Error: Can't subclass
```

Answer (score 7):

Other answers are already given enough understanding about final keyword. I want to explain by some example.

Consider below example without `final` Keyword.

```
class A {
   public var name: String
   var breed: String

    init(name: String, breed: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
    }
}
class B:A{
    override init(name: String, breed: String) {
        super.init(name: name, breed: breed)
    }
}
```

In above code it allow to overwrite the varible of it's super class. While Class with final keyword don't allow it. Refer below example.

```
final class A {
   public var name: String
   var breed: String

    init(name: String, breed: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
    }
}

class B:A{
    **//ERROR:inheritance from a final class 'A' class B**
    override init(name: String, breed: String) {
        super.init(name: name, breed: breed)
    }
}
```

> Above code will give error **inheritance from a final class A class B**