# Using final for subclass in swift

Tags: swift

I have two class A , B. B is the subclass of A. Can I use final for class B. I want to reduce the dynamic dispatch. What if there is method in class b that is overriding the class A method . How method dispatching will work?

```
class A {
     ///
}

final class B : Class A {

}
```

Comment: Adding final to class B should be fine, it just means that class cannot be extended further. It will still be able to use methods from class A and override them

Comment: in this case too compiler will able to optimize call ?

Comment: I believe so yes, might be worth checking the documentation though

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049783/what-is-the-difference-between-final-class-and-class/46049813

Comment: It is different. I am asking about final on subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can

Swift gives us a final keyword just for this purpose: when you declare a class as being final, no other class can inherit from it. This means they can’t override your methods in order to change your behavior – they need to use your class the way it was written.

The final keyword is a restriction on a class, method, or property that indicates that the declaration cannot be overridden. This allows the compiler to safely elide dynamic dispatch indirection.

So you can use it.